# Actionable Message on Android

Tags: android, microsoft-teams

Unless I'm mistaken, Actionable Message cards are not fully supported on Android. Can someone confirm this? If I try and send an Actionable Message to a channel, even the sample code provided by Microsoft, I'm able to click "Send Feedback" on Windows and get the comment box. But on Android, clicking "Send Feedback" does nothing. I've included the code I'm using below. I've also tried this with a legacy message card sample from Microsoft with the same result.

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "themeColor": "0072C6",
  "title": "Visit the Outlook Dev Portal",
  "text": "Click **Learn More** to learn more about Actionable Messages!",
  "potentialAction": [
    {
      "@type": "ActionCard",
      "name": "Send Feedback",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "@type": "TextInput",
          "id": "feedback",
          "isMultiline": true,
          "title": "Let us know what you think about Actionable Messages"
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "@type": "HttpPOST",
          "name": "Send Feedback",
          "isPrimary": true,
          "target": "https://e45ea2e9.proxy.webhookapp.com/",
          "headers": [
          {
          "name": "comment",
          "value": "test"
          }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@type": "OpenUri",
      "name": "Learn More",
      "targets": [
        { "os": "default", "uri": "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long-standing issue that Office 365 Connector cards have not worked properly on Teams mobile clients. This is just one example.

Our mobile team is making a big push on this area this summer and should have Office 365 Connector cards (including "actionable messages" which is what this is) as well as the new Adaptive Cards standard working on both iOS and Android by mid to late summer 2018